# MVVM Detect property change of subclass

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, inotifypropertychanged, simple-mvvm

I am using SimpleMVVM and have two separate classes (models), one using the second like this:

```
    public class Database : ModelBase<Database>
    {
        public String ServerName //{ get; set; }
        {
            get { return _ServerName; }
            set
            {
                if (_ServerName != value)
                {
                    _ServerName = value;
                    NotifyPropertyChanged(m => m.ServerName);
                }
            }
        }
        private String _ServerName = "MyTestServer";

        // other properties removed for brevity
    }

public class MyConfiguration
{
        /// <summary>
        /// Database information
        /// </summary>
        public Database DatabaseInfo
        {
            get { return _DatabaseInfo; }
            set
            {
                if (_DatabaseInfo != value)
                {
                    _DatabaseInfo = value;
                    NotifyPropertyChanged(m => m.DatabaseInfo);
                }
            }

        }
        private Database _DatabaseInfo = new Database();
}
```

When `'ServerName'` is changed, the `NotifyPropertyChanged(m => m.ServerName);` command executes but NOT `NotifyPropertyChanged(m => m.DatabaseInfo);`

How do I make the `NotifyPropertyChanged(m => m.DatabaseInfo);` fire whenever one of the properties of `Database` changes?

Comment: If you need to track changes in subclass property you can just subscribe to it's OnPropertyChanged event.

Comment: I have tried both methods below but the DataBasePropertyChanged method is never called.  Could this be due to the fact that these classes are both Models and not ViewModels?  Can I implement a PropertyChanged on a Model?

Comment: why you need this at all? if you bind anywhere in xaml to {Binding DatabaseInfo.ServerName} your ServerName value will be updated. why you need a property change for your DatabaseInfo too?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`PropertyChanged` event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.propertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx) of the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface to tell you when the child property changes.

In your `MyConfiguration` class:

```
public Database DatabaseInfo
{
    get { return _DatabaseInfo; }
    set
    {
        if (_DatabaseInfo != value)
        {
            _DatabaseInfo = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged(m => m.DatabaseInfo);
            DatabaseInfo.PropertyChanged += DataBasePropertyChanged;
        }
    }
}
```

...

```
private void DataBasePropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    NotifyPropertyChanged(m => m.DatabaseInfo);
}
```

Please note that you will need to attach this listener *each time* that you change the `DatabaseInfo` property value. Also, note that if you just wanted to listen to one property, then you could have done this:

```
private void DataBasePropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.PropertyName == "ServerName") NotifyPropertyChanged(m => m.DatabaseInfo);
}
```

Comment: I added this to MyConfiguration class but the DatabasePropertyChanged method never gets hit.  I did change the method name to DataBasePropertyChanged.

Comment: I've updated my answer... try moving the handler attachment to the `DatabaseInfo setter`.

Answer (score 0):

```
private Database _DatabaseInfo = new Database();

public MyConfiguration()
{
  this._DatabaseInfo.PropertyChanged += new PropertyChangedEventHandler(propChanged);
}

private void propChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
  // Now you can update the _DatabaseInfo.DatabaseInfo property to force the property changed event to fire.
}
```

Refer to the documentation here

[INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.propertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx)